# How to use Launch4J with obfuscated jar in Gradle

Tags: gradle, proguard, obfuscation, launch4j, shadowjar

I am trying to create an executable with Launch4J with my obfuscated jar but I have a problem. Every time I run the `createEXE` task via Gradle, the shadowJar task also runs causing my obfuscated jar to be overwritten.

How to I use my obfuscated jar with Launch4J's `createExe` task? Otherwise how do I stop `shadowJar` from running during the execution of `createExe`?

Here is my Launch4J task:

```
launch4j {
    jar = "${projectDir}/build/libs/plugin.jar"
    outfile = 'Plugin.exe'
    icon = "${projectDir}/etc/icon.ico"
    mainClassName = 'plugin.Driver'
    bundledJrePath = './jre'
    jreMinVersion = '1.8.0_161'
    jdkPreference = 'preferJdk'
}
```

Comment: So you are using shadowJar but also an obfuscated jar coming from... somewhere else ? What's generating it ?

Comment: @ToYonos I run shadowJar to create a jar with all the dependencies. I then obfuscate that jar using proguard via it's gui. I will later integrate that into Gradle. When I run the createExe task, it reruns shadowJar therefore overwriting and creating an executable of the non-obfuscated jar

Comment: Try `gradle -x shadowJar createExe`

Comment: @ToYonos It looks like it worked :) would you like to reply as an answer so I can mark it right? also What does the -x do exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just ignore the `shadowJar` task using the `-x` option. It tells Gradle to skip the specified task.

```
gradle -x shadowJar createExe
```

You can also do permanently like that :

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    if (taskGraph.hasTask(createExe)) {
        shadowJar.enabled = false
    }
}
```